# select text_field by clicking label in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form in Ruby on rails. I have a atributte called user_name. The problem is that I had to change the name the label of user_name a username and lost the capacity of that by clicking the label the cursor appears inside the text_field. I am a newbie

```
<%=form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%=f.label :username %>   
  <%=f.text_field :user_name %><br/>
</div>

<% end %>
```

html

## New user

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="cDfCEFXe9Nfi+UqtQ2ALAJdlXlDTaMA8qY3tBHFHdAE=" /></div>
<div class="field">
  <label for="user_username">Username</label>   
  <input id="user_user_name" name="user[user_name]" size="30" type="text" /><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need to change the literal that's displayed then you can do `<%= f.label :user_name, 'Username' %>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you had to change the 'name' (i.e `:username`) because that's what the text in the label had to be. The first argument for the label helper is the attribute identifier and there's an optional second argument for the text to show. Eg you can do this instead:

```
<%= f.label :user_name, 'Username' %>
```

If the second argument isn't given (like you have done), Rails tries to be smart and generate the label text based on the attribute name. You can read more about the label helper [in the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-label_tag).

Answer (score 1):

The id of the input and the "for" attribute of the label must match.

```html
<label for="foo">Foo</label>
<input id="foo" type="text">
```